# How to rename Request/Response object properties in ASP.Net MVC Web API?

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api, minify

Could you help me please to minimize response of my Web API Route.

```
public class Product
{
    public string UniqueId {get;set;}
    public string Title {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return repository.GetAll();
    }
    // ....
}
```

The response contains full names of the entity properties:

```
[{
    UniqueId: 123,
    Title: 'Book 1'
},...]
```

I would like to minimize traffic by using short aliases for DTO properties and see something like this:

```
[{
    u: 123,
    t: 'Book 1'
},...]
```

I'm wondering if special attributes could be used to rename properties in request/response.
BTW I'm talking about requests because I have the same issue for POST requests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try applying the following attribute on your DTO's properties:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName = "u")]
public string UniqueId {get; set;}
```

In this way, JSON.NET will know which name to use when serializing or deserializing your DTOs.

Comment: You can also do this without JSON.NET by adding [DataContract] attribute to your class and [DataMember(Name="u")] attribute to the property.